# configuring a nested if loop to categorize a dataset

Tags: python

i have a file with following data:

```
line   EF1    1     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
line   A2     1     C     Car   3.2     5.22    1.22
line   A1     1     C     Car   3.11    4.21    2.13
line   HF1    1     H     Hyd   7.11    5.11    7.11
line   EE2    1     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
line   A2     2     C     Car   3.2     5.22    1.22
line   EF1    2     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
line   EE2    2     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
line   A1     2     C     Car   3.11    4.21    2.13
line   HE2    2     H     Hyd   7.11    5.11    7.11
```

...1000+ lines.

Here column no 3 represents Chain number.
Now I have created different lists named : `EF` ,`EE`, `H` and `ace`.
What I wanted to do is, if `EF1` and `HE1` both present from same `chain number` then write `EF data` in `'EF list'` and `HE data` in `H list`. On the other hand if only `'EF1'` present but no `HE1` in the same `chain number` then write it in `'ace list'`.

Desired output is:

```
EF list: line  EF1   1  F   Flu   5.7   3.221   9.332
         line  EE2   2  F   Flu   5.7   3.221   9.332

H list: line   HF1   1  H   Hyd   7.11 5.11    7.11
        line   HE2   2  H   Hyd   7.11 5.11    7.11

ace list: line   EE2   1  F   Flu   5.7   3.221   9.332
          line   EF1   2  F   Flu   5.7   3.221   9.332
```

Now i was trying like,

```
inp = filename.read().strip().split('\n')
for line in map(str.split,inp):
    codeName = line[1]
    shortName = line[3]
```

now as a rookie i am really lost here about how could i be able construct an `if loop` to get this checking done.
please provide some ideas on how could i progress on this !!
(i was mistaken for my formatting error first time. corrected it!)

Comment: I do not completely get the logic, you want to group them by chain but while listing EF or EH or whatever they have both chains in desired output. Please explain a bit more to make it more clear.

Comment: If you enumerate your input file and label your desired output with the same index. This will be very helpful to create a methodology for your question.

Comment: @scriptmonster i am not getting way out with enumerate(). would you like to please explain a bit.?

Comment: By enumerate i mean, manually express the desired output's lines location in your input file. For example input file's first line is the output's first line, fifth line of is the second in the output.

Comment: no no!! i have given a glimpse of that file. Actual file contains 1000+ lines and they are random. The only way to track it is the chain number > analysis.. That's why i told enumerate() func wont working here. @scriptmonster

Comment: I really can't follow what are pairs here. It seems weird that you talk about "EF list" while there is an EE there. It also seems weird that "EF1" and "HE1" would be considered a pair? Could you explain better what constitutes a pair (whats the rule)?

Comment: I now assume the 3rd column, could you confirm?

Comment: I hope the answer provided correctly addresses the problem at hand, let me know if something is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First pass through the file:

The crucial part in my view is how to identify which form pairs. I used the following code snippet for it:

```
splitline = line.strip().split()
identifier = "".join(splitline[1:3])[1:]
# You could also write the following, if that makes it more clear: 
identifier = splitline[1][1:] + splitline[2]
```

Basically what `"".join(splitline[1:3])[1:]` does is to make from `HF1    1` the identifier string `F11` (it omits the first character) which is basically the thing that should be tested for if it occurs only in "F" or also in "H" (and vice versa).

In the example, both `EF1 with chain 1` and `HF1 with chain 1` would result in that identifier `F11`. The first time one of these occurs, it sets `categories['F11'] = 1`. When it finds the pair, it sets `categories['F11'] = 2`

Using this, we build a dictionary to store the result for these identifiers if they occur once or twice.

#### Having built the categories dictionary we can go through the file another time:

If in `categories` an identifier has the value `1`, then we know the line should be put in `ace`, if the value is `2`, we know we should write the entry to either `F` or `H`.

This solution will be quite fast as we are working with dictionaries; if you want to maintain order in the lists, let me know then I can update accordingly.

So here is the code:

```
infile = "overflow.txt"
result = {"F" : [], "H" : [], "ace" : []}
with open(infile) as f:
    # First pass through to build the dictionary of identifiers
    categories = {}
    for line in f:
        splitline = line.strip().split()
        identifier = "".join(splitline[1:3])[1:]
        if identifier not in categories:
            categories[identifier] = 1
        else:
            # If the identifier is already there, the value becomes 2.    
            categories[identifier] = 2
    # To go for a second pass through to create the lists
    f.seek(0)
    for line in f:
        splitline = line.strip().split()
        identifier = "".join(splitline[1:3])[1:]
        if categories[identifier] == 1:  # meaning the stem just occurs once
            if splitline[3] != "C":
                result["ace"].append(line.strip())
        else:
            result[splitline[3]].append(line.strip())
```

You can now access these groups by `result["H"]`, `result["F"]` and `result["ace"]`.

Here is the code to print the result:

```
for type in result:
    print("\n",type, "list:", "\n", "\n ".join(result[type]))
```

> ```
> H list: 
>   line   HF1    1     H     Hyd   7.11    5.11    7.11
>   line   HE2    2     H     Hyd   7.11    5.11    7.11
>
> F list: 
>   line   EF1    1     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
>   line   EE2    2     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
>
> ace list: 
>   line   EE2    1     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
>   line   EF1    2     F     Flu   5.7     3.221   9.332
> ```

Comment: I couldn't gather from the data you show so far that you also have "C" as a possibility in the cell after the chain? Is that correct?

Comment: your previous code is working nice so far. but what does this line mean actually i cant figure out > "if categories[identifier] == 1: "

Comment: `categories` is the object where we add "identifiers" (that which identifies whether or not the stem occurs several times). We are asking for the `identifier` (say `F11`, see the example) in categories. When we were building the dictionary, when the identifier does not occur we set it to 1. Then when the pair comes along, we set this value to 2. With `if categories[identifier] == 1` we thus check if the pair of chain and e.g. `HF1` also occurred (`EF1 with chain 1`). If it is `1` the pair did not occur and thus be should put in `ace`. Does that make sense? Feel free to ask more if isn't clear.

Comment: @abhisek After you run the code, feel free to inspect the `categories` object! It contains pairs of the identifiers with a value of either 1 or 2

Comment: `else: result[splitline[3]].append(line.strip())` would you please explain this line to me.!

Comment: The `else` part triggers when we know it has a pair and thus shouldn't be put in `ace`, but to instead put it in either `H` or `F`. `splitline[3]` contains the `H` or `F` from your line (the 4th element). `result[splitline[3]]` thus becomes e.g. `result["H"]`. `result["H"]` accesses the elements in that list. Using `.append`, we add the current line of the file we are iterating over to that list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to look more like this:

```
with open(filename) as inp:
    for line in inp:
        tokens = line.split()
        codeName = tokens[1]
        shortName = tokens[3]
```

You were failing to open the file at all, and the map() wasn't really helping you either.

Comment: Is your answer a complete solution to a problem above?

Comment: @John Zwinck not at all. I have opened  the file and it is in operational stage. But what i lack is my conception on designing a nested if loop to get the data sorted.

Comment: Well, the code in the OP didn't even open the file; I took it a step in the right direction and got a downvote for my trouble.  Tough crowd tonight.

Comment: @JohnZwinck i am sorry for that. But I did open the file well. I tried to emphasize in this question about the further categorization of data.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want a for loop there...

```
inp = filename.read().strip().split('\n')
inp = [line.split() for line in inp]
# sorts the input lines by the second column, so that groups appear together in order
inp = sorted(inp, key=itemgetter(1))
```

now you have a list of lines, split into columns

next you want to group them into chunks of lines whose second columns are the same, right?

```
cur_group = 1
groups_list = []
group = []
for line in inp:
    if int(line[1]) == cur_group:
        group.append(line)
    else:
        groups_list.append(group)
        group = [line]
        cur_group += 1
```

now you have a list of groups, and each group is a list of lines; your data looks like:

```
groups_list = [[['EF1',   '1',     'F',     'Flu',   '5.7',     '3.221',   '9.332'],
                 ...],
               [['A2',    '2', ... ],
                 ...],
               ...
              ]
```

Now you can check what you really wanted to know, which was whether for each EF in each group, there was a matching EH. I'm going to make a helper function for this:

```
def find_match(line, group, EH_list, EF_list):
    """
    returns false if no match found, returns true and appends line and match to appropriate lists otherwise
    """
    for pmatch in group:
        if line[0].startswith('EH') and pmatch[0].startswith('EF') and pmatch[0][2]==line[0][2]: # Match case 1
            EH_list.append(line)
            EF_list.append(pmatch)
            return True
        elif line[0].startswith('EF') and pmatch[0].startswith('EH') and pmatch[0][2]==line[0][2]: # Match case 2
            EF_list.append(line)
            EH_list.append(pmatch)
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

then the rest is simple and fairly straightforward:

```
for group in groups_list:
    for line in group:
        if line[0][0] == 'E' and not find_match(line, group, EH, EF):
            ace.append(line)
```

...and I think that should be it! I won't make any promises that this code will run right off the bat, but it should give you at the very least a good place to start

Answer (score 0):

You said that the order is random, so you cannot see whether or not a pair of entries exists just by going through the file line by line. Instead you need to remember ever unpaired entry so that you can check its existence once you see the other part.

So I’ll do that by remembering the *unmatched* entries in a dictionary where the Ex/Hx part and the chain number is the key. If, for a line, the paired entry is in the unmatched dictionary, I can remove it from there and add it to the correct list instead. Otherwise I add the line to the dictionary itself.

All unmatched entries that haven’t been consumed by the end, are automatically the entries for `ace`.

```
# initialize target lists and unmatched dictionary
E_list, H_list = [], []
unmatched = {}

with open('filename') as f:
    # loop over each line in the file
    for line in f:
        # split the line into parts separated by whitespace
        data = tuple(line.split())

        # `key` is the second column, `chain` the third
        key, chain = data[1], data[2]

        # `key` begins with an 'E'
        if key.startswith('E'):
            # The key of the paired value begins with an 'H' instead of 'E'
            pairKey = 'H' + key[1:]

            # The list for the current item will be `E_list`; the list for
            # the paired element will be `H_list`
            curList, pairList = E_list, H_list

        # `key` begins with an 'H'
        elif key.startswith('H'):
            # The key of the paired value begins with an 'E' instead of 'H'
            pairKey = 'E' + key[1:]

            # The list for the current item will be `H_list`; the list for
            # the paired element will be `E_list`
            curList, pairList = H_list, E_list

        # `key` stats with neither 'E' nor 'H', so skip this line
        else:
            continue

        # At this point we know that the current line has `key` as its
        # key, and `chain` as its chain. The element that should be paired
        # with it has `pairKey` as its key, and also `chain` as its chain.
        # If we have matched the paired element before, it will be in the
        # `unmatched` dictionary; if that’s the case, put the current element
        # into the list `curList`, and the paired element into the list
        # `pairList`.

        # Look up the paired element from the unmatched dictionary
        pair = unmatched.get((pairKey, chain), None)

        if pair:
            # If we found it, append the current and paired element to their
            # correct list …
            curList.append(data)
            pairList.append(pair)

            # … and remove the paired element from the unmatched set
            del unmatched[(pairKey, chain)]
        else:
            # Otherwise, if we didn’t found it, remember this item to be
            # paired with something later
            unmatched[(key, chain)] = data

# Finally, collect all elements that haven’t been matched yet, and
# put it into the `ace` list
ace = list(unmatched.values())
```

Used with your example data this yields:

```
>>> for l in E_list: print(l)
('line', 'EF1', '1', 'F', 'Flu', '5.7', '3.221', '9.332')
('line', 'EE2', '2', 'F', 'Flu', '5.7', '3.221', '9.332')
>>> for l in H_list: print(l)
('line', 'HF1', '1', 'H', 'Hyd', '7.11', '5.11', '7.11')
('line', 'HE2', '2', 'H', 'Hyd', '7.11', '5.11', '7.11')
>>> for l in ace: print(l)
('line', 'EF1', '2', 'F', 'Flu', '5.7', '3.221', '9.332')
('line', 'EE2', '1', 'F', 'Flu', '5.7', '3.221', '9.332')
```

One thing I wasn’t sure from your description was if the “key” (EF/EH + number) and the chain number are enough to uniquely identify the pair. If that’s not the case, then you might want to change which kind of data I use as the key for the dictionary.

Comment: ya! i have to change the key, not all time it is EF/EH. In my actual data-set sometime it comes as EE/HF/HE also. I was pretty confused initially on how to write.. @poke

Comment: @abhisek So does my answer help you then? Or do you need further help adjusting it to your updated data?

Comment: your answer is all ok. but all keys are not starting with 'E', as you can see from the recent update. a little more help would be appreciated regarding that anomaly ..

Comment: @abhisek Just for clarification: You have a list for `E` and `H` and `Ex` matches with `Hx` (i.e. `EF` with `HF` and `EE` with `HE`)? Do you have more than those combinations?

Comment: when i am running it i am not getting any pairs !! what does line "curList, pairList = E, H" does, i cant get the logic...

Comment: @abhisek I’ve updated my code to include detailed comments. Basically `a, b = c, d` is the same as doing `a = c` and `b = d`. Also, when you didn’t get any pairs, did you get entries in the `ace` list? Can you update your question to include a few examples from the list then? Otherwise if the `ace` list is also empty: Then either the file cannot be loaded, or the format isn’t correct after all. Please make sure then, that your question is really showing some example data from the actual file.